# Many-to-many query, MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, many-to-many

I have 3 tables like this:

**movies:**

- movie_id (int)
- movie_title (varchar)
- movie_runtime (int)
- movie_releaseYear (int)
- ...

**genres:**

- genre_id (int)
- genre_name (varchar)

**movieGenres:**

- movieGenre_id (int)
- movieGenre_movieId (int)
- movieGenre_genreId (int)

A movie can include many genres.
I want to grab the movie title, runtime and release year together with its genres. How can I do that in a single query?

I tried to do it like this:

```
SELECT u.movie_title, u.movie_runtime, u.movie_releaseYear, a.genre_name 
FROM movieGenres ua 
LEFT JOIN movies u ON u.movie_id = ua.movieGenre_filmId 
LEFT JOIN genres a ON a.genre_id = ua.movieGenre_genreId
LIMIT 0,10
```

This return something like:

Robin Hood _ 101 _ 2001 _ Adventure 
Robin Hood _ 101 _ 2001 _ Action 
Robin Hood _ 101 _ 2001 _ Drama 
Firewall _ 98 _ 2003 _ Action 
Firewall _ 98 _ 2003 _ Drama

I don't want to repeat the information I already know. I want it to display like this:

Robin Hood _ 101 _ 2001 _ Adventure _ Action _ Drama 
Firewall _ 98 _ 2003 _ Action _ Drama

Please help me figure this out:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    u.movie_title,
    u.movie_runtime,
    u.movie_releaseYear,
    GROUP_CONCAT(a.genre_name) genre
FROM
    movieGenres ua  
    INNER JOIN movies u ON u.movie_id = ua.movieGenre_filmId  
    INNER JOIN genres a ON a.genre_id = ua.movieGenre_genreId
GROUP BY
    u.movie_title,
    u.movie_runtime,
    u.movie_releaseYear
LIMIT 0,10 
;
```

This is essentially your query. I just added the [**GROUP BY**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) clause and [**GROUP_CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function. The default delimiter is a comma(,). If you want the list of genres space-separated, do this with the GROUP_CONCAT function:

```
SELECT
    u.movie_title,
    u.movie_runtime,
    u.movie_releaseYear,
    GROUP_CONCAT(a.genre_name SEPARATOR ' ') genre
FROM
    movieGenres ua  
    INNER JOIN movies u ON u.movie_id = ua.movieGenre_filmId  
    INNER JOIN genres a ON a.genre_id = ua.movieGenre_genreId
GROUP BY
    u.movie_title,
    u.movie_runtime,
    u.movie_releaseYear
LIMIT 0,10
;
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem a couple of weeks ago, and my professor gave me a pretty clever solution:

Use the Group_Concat function in a sub query to get the results as comma separated values, then use explode/split/whatever language equivalent to loop through the CSV results.

http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/

Hope this helps! This problem had me frustrated for awhile, but I think this is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way databases work.  There 'are' ways to do what you're wanting but honestly the database is usually not the right place to accomplish it.  Is this purely just an ad-hoc query or are these results going to an application?  The application would be the right place to format the results the way you want them if so.

Comment: I would disagree, the database is the perfect place to perform this as it takes some processing load off of the client.

Comment: @MichaelEakins Look at the nature of the data we're dealing with here.  Do you really think clients will do any processing with this data where speed will be an issue??  On the other hand, if this is on a web server processing a lot of request (like IMDB, for example) then you would *want* to move the processing to the client.

-1 on your comment for blindly making a blanket statement that is could be false as often as it is true.

Comment: touche, we are both correct in one regard then winform vs web.

Comment: Web vs WinForm isn't exactly the issue though I understand where you're coming from.  First question you ask is if there's even a need to bother distributing the workload for performance sake.  You don't go proactively wasting development time for that purpose if there's not a need, and especially not in this case since the application is much better suited to formatting data then the database is.  If there is a need then you distribute it as necessary, and while Web apps tend to have the higher volume than WinForm apps that's not necessarily the case.

Comment: Queries are simple, so saying that designing the query is performing overwork would suggest that queries are more difficult than code to write.

Comment: So simple that he had to come ask for help writing it, right? Haha :)  SQL is not hard to write when you use it for what it's designed to do.  It's not designed to do formatting.  And it's not just about which place it's easier to format data.  It's about how you will have to requery the database now if you need to use this data for anything else (or unformat it first).  This is why business objects exist.  Am I saying his approach is absolutely wrong?  Maybe not if this is a contained project that isn't going to do anything else.  But probably so if it's going to grow and do more.